# Firebase storage.rules version 2

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

Today when deploying, I noticed the following warning:

```sh
i  firebase.storage: checking storage.rules for compilation errors...
⚠  [W] undefined:undefined - Ruleset uses old version (version [1]). Please update to the latest version (version [2]).
✔  firebase.storage: rules file storage.rules compiled successfully
```

I am assuming the changes to `storage.rules` from v1 to v2 match [those of `firestore.rules`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#security_rules_version_2), but I would like to confirm this. However, all documentation that I can find for `storage.rules` makes no mention of rules versions for this file.

Is my assumption correct?

Note that the question is not "what is the current version" but rather "where is documentation describing changes from the previous version".

Answer (score 0):

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-language

> Firebase Security Rules leverage flexible, powerful, custom languages that support a wide range of complexity and granularity. You can make your Rules as specific or as general as makes sense for your app. Realtime Database rules use a syntax that looks like JavaScript in a JSON structure. Cloud Firestore and Cloud Storage rules use a language based on the Common Expression Language (CEL), that builds on CEL with match and allow statements that support conditionally granted access.

> The syntax statement indicates the version of the Firebase Rules language used to write the source. The latest version of the language is v2.

> If no rules_version statement is supplied, your rules will be evaluated using the v1 engine.

Cloud Firestore and Cloud Storage rules use same the Firebase Rules language.

You can specify the version of the Firebase Rules language  using the `rules_version` statement.

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  // Your 'match' blocks with their corresponding 'allow' statements and
  // optional 'function' declarations are contained here
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is not "how do I specify a version of the rules to use", it is instead "how did the semantics of the rules file change from v1 to v2?". There is clear documentation of all changes (few though they are) for changes from v1 to v2 of `firestore.rules`, but *no* documentation stating whether the version change in `storage.rules` is the same or different. Because these are security rules, I must know what the differences are before I can reasonably apply them to my application.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the documentation describing changes from the previous version. I think the version change in storage.rules is the same. But Cloud Firestore and Cloud Storage rules use same the Firebase Rules language.

Comment: Yeah, I'm stuck there too... I can't find anything about `storage.rules` changes, so I can only assume it's the same... but if I'm wrong, the implications are too risky... can't afford accidental access to parts of storage :)